# Firebase can't get chat messages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently trying to implement a simple chat service in my app using firebase. I followed the tutorial [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397)

I am not getting errors but for some unknown reason I can't see the chatmessages in my listview. Here's my code:

MainActivity.java

```
private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;

private final int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 123;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
        // Start sign in/sign up activity
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .build(),
                SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE
        );
    } else {
        // User is already signed in. Therefore, display
        // a welcome Toast
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Welcome " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                        .getCurrentUser()
                        .getDisplayName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        // Load chat room contents
        displayChatMessages();
    }

    FloatingActionButton fab =
            (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);

            // Read the input field and push a new instance
            // of ChatMessage to the Firebase database
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference()
                    .push()
                    .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                                    .getCurrentUser()
                                    .getDisplayName())
                    );

            // Clear the input
            input.setText("");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Successfully signed in. Welcome!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            displayChatMessages();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            // Close the app
            finish();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_sign_out) {
        AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "You have been signed out.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                        // Close activity
                        finish();
                    }
                });
    }
    return true;
}

private void displayChatMessages() {
    ListView listOfMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,
            R.layout.message, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };

    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Module:build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

As, suggested after I put the log in populateView, with the value of my message, it oddly only show the first two of my messages in firebase database but repeatedly. (I have 14 messages in my firebase with 2 different user)

> 05-25 15:23:51.470 12946-12946/? D/asd: jahshss
>   05-25 15:23:51.470 12946-12946/? D/asd: fhci
>   05-25 15:23:51.470 12946-12946/? D/asd: jahshss
>   05-25 15:23:51.470 12946-12946/? D/asd: fhci
>   05-25 15:23:51.500 12946-12946/? D/asd: jahshss
>   05-25 15:23:51.500 12946-12946/? D/asd: fhci
>   05-25 15:23:51.510 12946-12946/? D/asd: jahshss
>   05-25 15:23:51.510 12946-12946/? D/asd: jahshss
>   05-25 15:23:51.590 12946-13127/? D/FA: Connected to remote service
>   05-25 15:23:51.680 12946-12946/? D/asd: jahshss
>   05-25 15:23:51.690 12946-12946/? D/asd: jahshss
>   05-25 15:23:51.690 12946-12946/? D/asd: fhci
>   05-25 15:23:51.690 12946-12946/? D/asd: jahshss
>   05-25 15:23:51.700 12946-12946/? D/asd: fhci

jahshss is my first message value, and fhci is my second message value in firebase database.

Comment: put log inside populate view to see it data is coming from server or not

Comment: it is being called 10 times, but actually I have put 14 messages with 2 different user.

Comment: then listview should shows 10 entries

Comment: i have update the question, thank you

Comment: add listOfMessages.notifyDataSetChanged() a\at last

Comment: I think you mean adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), sorry it still doesn't work